# Cannot use agora_gaming_rtc

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer, agora.io

Im a newbie to Agora. I was try to have online communication for my Unity project and was trying on Agora.

I downloaded the latest voice sdk from unity assets store and checked many times if I had got any mistake from the youtube tutorial but still dont know why unity 2023 cannot support on agora_gaming_rtc as I watch other VR related youtubers can use it without problem. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvGyN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I belive the Agora SDK has been updated and "using agora_gaming_rtc;" is now "using Agora.Rtc;"

If you follow the documentation on this page it should work
https://docs.agora.io/en/video-calling/get-started/get-started-sdk?platform=unity